# current time minus mod_date_time

Tags: date, time, subtraction

I want to be able to subtract the current time from the `mod_date_time` field.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME - CURRENT_TIME WHERE USER_ID = '12345' * 24 * 60 "INTERVAL IN MINUTES"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT (MOD_DATE_TIME - SYSDATE) * 24 * 60
FROM PROD_TRKG_TRAN
WHERE USER_ID = '12345';
```